# I not getting the correct value of my variable in command prompt using for loop

Tags: batch-file, for-loop, cmd

I have this batch file

```
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
SET count=1
FOR /F "tokens=* USEBACKQ" %%F IN (`find "@  STATISTICS ON CLIENT_JE_AMT EY_ENT_DATE EY_EFF_DATE" "z_B10_VALIDATION.LOG"`) DO (
  SET var!count!=%%F
  SET /a count=!count!+1
)
ECHO %var1%
ECHO %var2%

for /f "tokens=1 delims=:" %%i in ("%var2%") do (
set stat_line_start=%%i
)
echo %stat_line_start%
set /a stat_line_end=!stat_line_start!+3

for /L %%j in (%stat_line_start%,1,%stat_line_end%) do (
echo %%j

set k=%%j

set cfirst=%k:~0,1%
set csec=%k:~1,1%
set cthird=%k:~2,1%

findstr /B "[%cfirst%-%cfirst%][%csec%-%csec%][%cthird%-%cthird%]:" "z_B10_VALIDATION.LOG">> z_STATS.txt
)
ENDLOCAL
```

when i run this, I am getting the correct value for variable "k" but having error on "cfirst", "csec" and "cthird" variable.
sample result line :

```
set k=254
set cfirst=~0,1
```

instead of

```
set cfirst=2
```

I am new on this field and just starting to explore. Hope you can help me.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: You've enabled delayed expansion, but you aren't using it. Any variable that you set inside of a `for` loop should be called with `!variable!` instead of `%variable%`.

Comment: Wow! this actually worked! thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CMD expands variables when the command is parsed, not when it is run.

Because code blocks (i.e. chunks of code suurrounded by parentheses - like multi-line `if` statements and `for` loops) are considered a single command by the interepreter, any variables that you set inside of the block are set to the default value: nothing.

You can delay this expansion to runtime with the command `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion` (which you already included at the top of your code) and using the `!variable!` syntax instead of the `%variable%` syntax.